# Place Toastr toasts in container in specific component

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-toastr

Toastr allows you to globally define container, where toasts are displayed in this way:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { ToastrModule, ToastContainerModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    ToastrModule.forRoot({ positionClass: 'inline' }), // <-- this
    ToastContainerModule,                              // <-- lines
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I want to achieve something similar, I want to place these toasts in a specific container but **only within one component**, so that it doesn't affect the rest of the toasts in the rest of the application.
This is a pure component, no module or route.

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

What we did is to define a custom container on `AppComponent` in order to re-use it as needed from other components.

So first you define a custom container in the template (pretty much like how it is explained in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr#put-toasts-in-your-own-container)). **Beware** that currently (2023-11-14) the docs are a bit outdated, instead of importing `ToastContainerModule` you now have to import `ToastContainerDirective` (which is now standalone) in either a standalone component or in the corresponding module (in our case in `AppModule`):

So in `AppModule` we have:

```js
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    // ...    
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    ToastContainerDirective
  ],
```

And on the `app.component.html` template:

```html
<!-- custom toastr container -->
<div toastContainer aria-live="polite"></div>
<router-outlet> ... </router-outlet>
```

The big difference to the docs, is that we don't add `{ positionClass: 'inline' }` as a "global" option on the module-import, but instead define different components and options for different use cases and leave the default as an overlay.

Because we wanted to re-use the custom-inline container (and several others) in any component, we do all the configuration in a service e.g. CustomToastrService. Also, if you want to change the layout(s) you'll need custom component(s).

In the service you can define methods for different combinations of options/custom components, depending on your needs:

```
export type ToastOptions = {msg: string; type: 'error'|'success'|...; title?: string; ...};

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class CustomToastrService {
  constructor(private toastrService: ToastrService) { 
    //... 
  }

  /* Show a toastr inline */
  public showInlineToastr(options: ToastOptions) {
    const toastOptions = {
      toastClass: `ngx-toastr toast-${options.type}`,
      positionClass: 'inline',
      // ... more options
    };
    this.toastrService.show(options.msg, options.title, toastOptions);
  }

  /* Show a toast as an overlay on the top and full-width */
  public showToast(options: ToastOptions) {
    const toastOptions = {
      toastClass: `ngx-toastr toast-${options.type}`,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width',
      // ... more options
    };
    this.toastrService.show(options.msg, options.title, toastOptions);
  }

  // Use a custom component
  public showCustomToast(options: ToastOptions) {
    const toastOptions = {
      toastClass: '', // we set this in the template
      toastComponent: CustomToastComponent,
      // ...
    };
    this.toastrService.show(options.msg, options.title, toastOptions);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply configurations while triggering a toastr. Check the code below.

```
this.toastr.success('Textt', 'Text2', {
  positionClass: 'top-right',
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this but I want to place these toasts in a specific container, this code snippet will place them above the entire page content.

Added necessary clarification to original question.

Comment: I am not clear about your requirement. You need to place the toaster at a specific position in the DOM, Is that so ?

Comment: Scenario:
I have a pure component and a div.container in it's template.
I want to place the toasts launched in this component in this container.
In the rest of the application, the toasts are to be displayed in a standard way.